# How to find the numbers that are leftover after you've used sample once before on R?

Tags: r, sample

I want to use the numbers that are left over from the previous round of sampling for my next step, so how do i exclude the numbers that have already been used?
For example in:
`k <- sample(1:9, size = 5, replace = FALSE)`
I get a set of 5 random numbers. How do i find out the leftover numbers and then sample those only?

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1234)
k <- sample(1:9, size = 5, replace = FALSE)
k
[1] 6 5 4 1 8
leftovers <- setdiff(1:9, k)
leftovers
[1] 2 3 7 9
```

Comment: Yep.  (Maybe use `<-` consistently, and assign `1:9` to a variable?)  The easiest answer is to of course sample _once_ for a larger set.